# Oracle IN vs Exists difference?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am confused with oracle `IN` and `EXISTS`. I have below requirement.

I need to get all the employees whose names are in-

```
select * from emp where ename in('smith','brown','john','johnson');
```

Can i use `EXISTS` here? Also `IN` clause has 1000 limitation. Does `EXISTS` also has any such limitation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

simply put, `EXISTS` is usually used for checking whether rows that meet a criteria exist in another (or the same) table.

your SQL using `EXISTS` would look like this:

```
select *
from   emp e
where  exists(select * from emp e2 where e.empno = e2.empno and e2.ename in ('smith', 'brown', 'john', 'johnson'))
```

so you can see it's not what you need here

Comment: Thanks for your reply. does it mean exists would always return true/false? IN returns actual values?  in my case i should not use EXISTS right? Thanks!

Comment: `EXISTS` returns true/false, as does `IN`, the main difference between the two is the way that the query optimizer structures the query plan.

Answer (score 3):

`IN` picks the list of matching values. `EXISTS` returns the boolean values like true or false. Exists is faster than in.

Example

IN

```
select ename from emp e where mgr in(select empno from emp where ename='KING');
```

EXISTS

```
select ename from emp e 
  where exists (select 1 from emp where e.mgr = empno and ename = 'KING');
```

Comment: *" list of matching values. EXISTS returns the boolean values like true or false. "* Please prove this assertion with some benchmarks. Because as a bald statement it is **false**. `exists` is more efficient for certain types of queries, `in` is more efficient in other cases.