# Any way to write this without using a join

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering if it would be possible to write this without a join using something like a
IN keyword, if so would it be better then what I wrote below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor_name
FROM vendors JOIN invoices
    ON vendors.vendor_id = invoices.vendor_id
ORDER BY vendor_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query might be a more efficient way of running the query:

```
SELECT vendor_name
FROM vendors v
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM invoices i
              WHERE v.vendor_id = i.vendor_id
             );
```

For best performance, you would want an index on `invoices(vendor_id)` and `vendors(vendor_name, vendor_id)`.

First, I prefer the `join` version because I think it is more clearly written.  But, this has the following advantages:

1. It eliminates the `select distinct` (by assuming that vendor names are already unique).  That saves an aggregation for running the distinct.
2. Without the aggregation, the query can process the vendor ids in order using the index on `vendors`.
3. `exists` often has better performance characteristics than `in`.

As a note, this won't have the best performance when the `invoices` table is much smaller than `vendors`.

Comment: You are assuming that vendors have **unique** names, right?

Comment: @PM77-1 . . . Yes, and I have listed that as an explicit assumption.

Comment: regarding point 3, it is also true that `in`  often has better performance characteristics than `exists`.   It depends on the ratio of Vendors to Invoices.  In this case, as it is likely that Vendors is small and Invoices is large, EXISTS should be the more efficient operation.

Comment: @APC . . . Whether `exists` works better than `in` depends on a number of factors, including the version of Oracle.  The general consensus that I see is that `exists` is preferable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896007/oracle-in-vs-exists-difference, http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-sql-statements.php).  Two small notes:  `not exists` *is* preferable to `not in` because of semantic differences in the handling of `NULL` values.  And, `exists` is almost never *worse* than `in` on any database.

Answer (score 0):

Although a join is the preferred approach, converting it to `IN` would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor_name
FROM vendors
WHERE vendor_id IN (select vendor_id from invoices)
ORDER BY vendor_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor_name
FROM vendors, invoices
WHERE vendors.vendor_id = invoices.vendor_id
ORDER BY vendor_name;
```

Comment: C'mon. It's still a `JOIN`.

Comment: Actually, that's still a join, but it's using the old SQL-89 syntax

Comment: Considering author is talking about `join` operator. Anyway, prob any query for this particular case will be translated into join operator.