# Diff between IN and EXIST in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

IN Vs EXISTS:

point 1:

In: Effective when sub-query contains less number of rows compared to outer query

Exist: Effective when sub-query contains large number of rows compared to outer query. sub-query returns either TRUE or FALSE. Outer query is executed once and for every value in outer query sub-query executes

but in recent versions of Oracle they will tend to be rewritten by the optimizer to be the same, using the same execution plan(Found this point in Google). Execution plan is same for both IN and EXIST(Observed in my PC)

Point 2:

I've searched in google for the diff between NOT IN and NOT EXIST. But  most of them suggested both are same.

My Questions:

Question 1(Point 1):was my assumption correct? If both are treated in same way by oracle then can we use either IN or EXIST in queries??

Question 2(Point 2): Can someone please explain why both are same?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896007/oracle-in-vs-exists-difference. The difference is also in handling null values

Comment: I've always thought EXIST to be more performant since that statement is counting records, while the IN statement is listing a series of actual values. The first seems easier to process : if 1 record is found, no need to search further, because the EXIST boolean clause is known already. While with IN, he may need to go through all kind of values. No wonder that the IN clause originated as a list of exact values ('A','B','C'), and in that context, the EXIST clause is really different.

Answer (score 0):

It might be very well uses the same optimization path nowadays, they are not different,

aside of this, obviously
EXISTS accepts subquery  and IN supports subquery and expression list.

in some cases you will have to use IN condition.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Oracle has changed the meaning of those two things in 12C then you are not understanding what they do.

The IN function takes a list of values to run a query against. Given:

select * from foo where bar in ( 1,4,3)  ;

This evaluates to:

select * from foo where bar = 1 or bar = 4 or bar = 3  ;

The EXIST function allows you to get a substantial performance improvement when selecting by a sub query, eg:

select * from foo where where EXISTS ( select * from xfoo where xbar = Z );

Without EXISTS the entire sub-query must be completely evaluated.

With EXISTS the sub-query need only satisfy the very first element it finds.  ie: if the sub query results in 10,000 rows then as soon as the system finds 1 row, the sub-query returns true and the main query is satisfied.