# Execution of Exists in sql server

Tags: sql, exists

As we know all are saying `EXISTS` is good over `IN` clause. I have question ever which not answered every time.

when we use `Exists`, is complete execution of inner query while it get first record or it will continue execution for all records??

Comment: A simple google search would have given you the answer :)  @Dinesh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[NOT] EXISTS operator gives best performance when the subquery i.e. driven query contains huge volume of data. The reason is that it follows the principle of ‘At least found’ in queries. It is set to TRUE, if at least one record is found in the subquery correlating with the main driving query, and stops further scanning of the table. Unlike other comparison operators like [NOT] IN, LIKE and others, which returns data for comparison, [NOT] EXISTS return BOOLEAN output.

You can find more detailed illustrations in the link  :

http://www.dbanotes.com/database-development/using-exists-in-oracle-sql-queries/

Comment: I have no clue where you get your information, but I suggest a new source. `in`, `like` and your so-called "others" are also boolean operators that stop as soon as data is found.

Comment: Well I referred to the above link and the link below, if thats what u r asking for when to refer to "source" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896007/oracle-in-vs-exists-difference @Blindy

Comment: Nobody here mentioned Oracle but you, if that's even true for it.

Answer (score 1):

both `exists` and `in` are the same. Any sane query plan optimizer will produce the same plan for them both.

```
-- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97c87/1
select *
from t1
where name in (select name from t2)
```

This query will produce the plan:

[image: plan 1]

```
-- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97c87/2
select *
from t1
where exists (select name from t2 where t2.name=t1.name)
```

And this second query will produce the plan:

[image]

As you can see, both are identical.